# Installing and Configuring Apache 2.4 on windows

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, https

I have been tasked with Installing and Configuring Apache 2.4 on a windows server for the following purpose:

1. Configure SSL through apache
2. Apache Tomcat also installed on server to handle web request to a specific web application - MySQL db also on the same server.

How does one go about installing and configuring SSL through apache 2.4 on Windows Server 2012?

I have read so many documents and so many questions on forums etc and is now more confused than before. 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-windows-server-2008-iis-7.0.html

So far i have download and installed apache as a service and created the Certificate service request from OPENSSL (downloaded and installed also).

All I need to do now is :

1. How does one import these certificates in apache ?
2. How do you test if the import was successful and if ssl is working ?
3. How to redirect Apache to Apache tomcat to serve the webpage

Can someone please outline the steps require and if possible how to perform these steps for apache in Windows.

Thanks.

Regards,

Robert Ramoutar.

Answer (score 0):

> How does one import these certificates in[to] Apache [httpd]?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_faq.html#realcert

> How do you test if the import was successful and if SSL is working?

Connect to the server using a web browser with HTTPS. If it works, and the certificate looks the way you wanted it to look and you don't get an errors/warnings, then you are good.

> How to redirect Apache [httpd] to Apache Tomcat to serve the web page

You need to use a module for reverse-proxying like `mod_proxy`. Read the documentation for [mod_proxy_http](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) to see how to set one up.

Comment: when you say connect to a browser using https: do you mean just do:  "https://localhost:443" OR     "https://mywebsite.com"

Comment: @Robert You need to use the hostname present in the TLS certificate, otherwise you are going to get warnings. Use whatever URL you expect your users to get in order to properly test the behavior.